# How to retrieve an authenticated user data with Firestore in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-security

I'm playing around with Firebase and I'm using their authentication framework plus Firestore database.

My database model is quite simple: I want to keep a collection "users" which will hold a document -identified by the user's uid- for each registered user. This user document will hold a collection of documents representing user expenses.
Following [their documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-conditions) I've set up the rules in the firebase console as shown beneath:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /users/{userId=**} {
        allow read, update, delete: if request.auth.uid == userId;
        allow create: if request.auth.uid != null;
    }
  }
}
```

And in my iOS app, when user logs in, I want to retrieve the user's expenses with the following code:

```
  func retrieveUserExpenses() {
    guard let dbRef = userExpensesDbRef() else {
      print("Attempting to retrieve expense for unlogged user")
      return
    }

    dbRef.getDocuments { [unowned self] (snapshot, err) in
      if let err = err {
        print("Error retrieving expenses \(err)")
      } else {
        print("Retrieved expenses!")
        snapshot?.documents.forEach {
          if let expense = self.createExpenseFromDocument($0) {
            self.expenses.append(expense)
          }
        }
        self.loadedExpenses = true
      }
    }
  }

  private func userExpensesDbRef() -> CollectionReference? {
    guard let loggedInUser = AuthHandler.shared.loggedInUser() else {
      return nil
    }
    return db.collection("users").document(loggedInUser.uid).collection("expenses")
  }
```

The thing is that the call to getDocuments prints the error line:

> Error retrieving expenses Error Domain=FIRFirestoreErrorDomain Code=7
>   "Missing or insufficient permissions."

I've checked by printing that this: *loggedInUser.uid* is the same one I see on the Firebase Console in the Authentication section in the Users tab.

Any guidance or tip on where I'm failing to securely retrieve the data is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is this AuthHandler object that you use to retrieve loggedInUser? I'm having an issue in which my user is logged in via the main target (on the device), but my extension fails to recognize the user with let user = Auth.auth().currentUser.

Answer (score 0):

Go in Database -> Rules ->

Change allow read, write: if false; to true;

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read: if true;
      allow write: if false;
    }
  } 
}
```

Comment: service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
     match /{document=**} {
       allow read: if true;
       allow write: if false;
      }
   }
}

Comment: I do not want to allow indiscriminate reading of data. Plus, I want each user to be able to write or update his data.